# WebView{1} Developer Machine VS Deployment VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, webview

Can anyone think of a reason why a Form with webview{1} would not load on a different PC (Deployment) but will work on the original developer machine. The Dll is packaged there is no exception being thrown. The form just will not load.

The ONLY source on form1 is

```
Settings.show()
```

{Which shows the settings form}

The rest of the source is run from Form2 but nothing is triggered on Form_Load so its happening sometime after the button click_event and has to do with the WebView (I believe) as that is really the only other component there outside of labels , buttons, a timer {not enabled} and a textbox.

If anyone has experienced this or knows why, Please let me know. This has been tested on 3 more machines and the form just won't show.

I've added WebView to different forms on new projects. Same results. It will work on my machine but not on any test machine.

The output in all cases on all forms show

2 Threads Exiting with Code 0 (no exceptions are being thrown)

This is true in all applications outside of my Developer machine that has a WebView control

Answer (score 0):

The issue was WebView1 (Edge) is not compatible when being run as admin. Seeing as I was working on my Azure Virtual Machine the application and Visual Studio (So even debugging) was being run as Admin. It cause the thread to close and the form would not load.

If anyone ever has this issue. Make sure you are not running as admin or if you are on a Virtual Desktop as the admin. Create a "user" with lower levels. That worked for me.